# Converting time-bin diagram to second order correlation function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, laser

Considering characterization of single photon sources a second order correlation function $g()$ is used to determine the purity of a single photon source, specifically its value at $g(0)$. Now imagine we have an experimental setup and record coincidences between two detector as a function of the delay between "start" and "stop" clicks. As a result we get a statistical time-bin diagram. How can this bin diagram be represented as $g()$ function? What's the procedure of converting one to another?